# Alternative to error_log in Joomla?

Tags: logging, joomla

I'm looking for a tool to log in different levels in Joomla. Any tips?

Something like

```
JLOG::trace($msg);
JLOG::error($msg);
```

Preferably with option to specify which file to log to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm stupid.

https://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog

I will not delete the question to enhance googling in the future.

Comment: Note that there's http://joomla.stackexchange.com/, which is a Joomla-specific stack exchange site.